# Django "Did you mean?" query

Tags: python, django, spell-checking

I am writing a fairly simple Django application where users can enter string queries. The application will the search through the database for this string.

```
Entry.objects.filter(headline__contains=query)
```

This query is pretty strait forward but not really helpful to someone who isn't 100% sure what they are looking for. So I expanded the search.

```
from django.utils import stopwords

results = Entry.objects.filter(headline__contains=query)
if(!results):
    query = strip_stopwords(query)
    for(q in query.split(' ')):
        results += Entry.objects.filter(headline__contains=q)
```

I would like to add some additional functionality to this. Searching for miss spelled words, plurals, common homophones (sound the same spelled differently), ect. I was just wondering if any of these things were built into Djangos query language. It isn't important enough for me to write a huge algorithm for I am really just looking for something built in.

Thanks in advance for all the answers.

Comment: You're looking for a "Soundex" search algorithm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex

Comment: Eh ... Soundex was originally intended to catch clerical errors with English surnames. It is less useful with general vocabulary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

djangos orm doesn't have this behavior out-of-box, but there are several projects that integrate django w/ search services like:

- sphinx ([django-sphinx](http://github.com/dcramer/django-sphinx/tree/master))
- solr, a lightweight version of lucene ([djangosearch](https://code.google.com/p/django-solr-search/))
- lucene ([django-search-lucene](http://code.google.com/p/django-search-lucene/))

I cant speak to how well options #2 and #3 work, but I've used django-sphinx quite a lot, and am very happy with the results.

Answer (score 11):

You could try using python's [difflib](http://docs.python.org/library/difflib) module.

```
>>> from difflib import get_close_matches
>>> get_close_matches('appel', ['ape', 'apple', 'peach', 'puppy'])
['apple', 'ape']
>>> import keyword
>>> get_close_matches('wheel', keyword.kwlist)
['while']
>>> get_close_matches('apple', keyword.kwlist)
[]
>>> get_close_matches('accept', keyword.kwlist)
['except']
```

Problem is that to use difflib one must build a list of words from the database. That can be expensive. Maybe if you cache the list of words and only rebuild it once in a while.

Some database systems support a search method to do what you want, like PostgreSQL's [`fuzzystrmatch`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/fuzzystrmatch.html) module. If that is your case you could try calling it.

---

**edit:**

For your new "requirement", well, you are out of luck. No, there is nothing built in inside django's query language.

Answer (score 0):

```
cal_name = request.data['column']['name']

        words = []
        for col in Column.objects.all():
            if cal_name != col.name:
                words.append(col.name)
        words = difflib.get_close_matches(cal_name, words)
        if len(words) > 0 and is_sure != "true":
            return Response({
                'potential typo': 'Did you mean ' + str(words) + '?',
                "note": "If you think you do not have a typo send {'sure' : 'true'} with the data."})
```